# Silverlight 4 with WCF RIA architecture applying DDD

Tags: silverlight, architecture, silverlight-4.0, domain-driven-design, wcf-ria-services

In my ASP.NET MVC applications I use DDD and it works very well. I'm new to Silverlight development and would like to know how could I apply DDD to build a new architecture.
I had a look on WCF RIA Services and what is exposed by default it's the simple CRUD methods.
I would like to use MVVM pattern.

I thought about general architecture and don't know if what I'm thinking about make sense in Silverlight development.

I thought about creating Domain Model on the top of SVC. I would than expose by WCF RIA some operation that deals with aggreates in my Domain Model instead of simple CRUD. What I would aloso expose is the ViewModel entieties that could be used by the view.

I don't know if it's make sense, if I'm going in a good direction or if applying DDD in Silverlight 4 development is a good practice. I didn't find much informations on Internet.

I'll appreciate if you could point me to some interesting links or if you can give me some hints.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

I took a look at RIA during a Silverlight 3 prototype.  I was initially excited, but ultimately ditched it.  I, too, was using DDD on the server-side.  I felt like RIA was very data-oriented and CRUD-oriented which, in my opinion, flies in the face of domain-oriented methods and operations.  While it does seem possible to make your own custom methods to expose on your RIA Domain Services (I hate that they called them "domain services" -- again in conflict with DDD), I felt like I was carrying a lot of RIA baggage for very little benefit once I ditched their default CRUD/query support.

Comment: We tried the same, doing DDD in the silverlight 4 project but eventually we ditched RIA and started using our own WCF services isntead of RIA Services.